# Can I alter an aspx.vb file on the fly on a live website?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I need to know if it recompiles my site at all or if there are any issues doing this. I have tested the changes locally and in a test environment and I don't want to do a full deployment for one tiny change. I'm just not familiar with aspx.vb files and how they interact with a website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is yes, it will cause the page to be dynamically recompiled. Dependencies could cause the entire site to be recompiled.

For more information read this MSDN article: [Understanding ASP.NET Dynamic Compilation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366723.aspx). The "Recompiling on Change" section addresses your question.

You can modify an `.aspx.vb` file and drop it into its respective location on the server, overwriting the existing file, and it will be dynamically compiled due to the change. However, if you were referring to having code that changed `.vb` file content on the fly, that sounds like a bad idea and you should reconsider your problem and approach.

Comment: Nope I am doing just what you said, copying the changed file over an existing one. Thanks so much for your response.